# Get a term object using getEntityRecords

Tags: rest-api, block-editor

Given a term ID, how can I fetch the term object by its ID using `getEntityRecords`?

I have a custom taxonomy with the slug `genre`.

```js
getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'genre' );
```

Currently this retrieves all terms under genre, but I'd like to retrieve the term which matches ID.
Can I pass the taxonomy ID somewhere in the above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'genre' )` will make a request to the "list terms" endpoint at `/wp/v2/genre` (or `/wp/v2/<rest_base>` if your taxonomy uses a custom [`rest_base`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#parameters)) in the REST API, and because the "list terms" endpoint for custom taxonomies by default use the same parameters used by `/wp/v2/categories` (the "list terms" endpoint for the built-in `category` taxonomy), if you want to limit the result set to specific term IDs, then you can use the [`include` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#arguments) like so:

```js
const termId = 123;

// The optional third parameter is an object which contains arguments for the
// specific REST API endpoint. On successful requests, this will be an array of
// term objects.
const terms = getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'genre', { include: [ termId ] } );

console.log( terms && terms[0] ? terms[0].name : terms );
```

But instead of using `getEntityRecords()`, you might want to just use `getEntityRecord()` to get a single term object/data:

```js
const termId = 123;

// The third parameter is mandatory and it is the term ID.
const term = getEntityRecord( 'taxonomy', 'genre', termId );

console.log( term?.name );
```

And if you don't already know, you can make a request to `/wp/v2` (e.g. `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2`) to see all the registered routes and endpoints, and the parameters for each endpoint.